# Livecode command keystrokes

Tags: development-environment, livecode, keystrokes

Is there a way to drag a stack window while developing on the MAC OS other than at the bar at the top of the window?  If I can't see the top bar and try to drag somewhere in the middle of the stack window, it activates that group, object, etc.  The only success I have is using the 'Size and position' on the stack properties window.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: To LiveCode users, it is perfectly clear what is being asked. The question is tagged LiveCode. Stephan Muller, bytebuster, hutchoid, Leeor and Harry clearly have no clue what LiveCode is. If you don't know LiveCode, then stay away from this question and you definitely shouldn't flag it! This question must be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in the IDE, you can type command-M to display the message box and type the following code in the message box:

```
set the loc of this stack to the screenLoc
```

This will usually move the top of the window to a visible part of the screen. You could also use

```
set the top of this stack to 100
```

which will move the title bar down to 100 pixels below the top of the screen.

If you want to move a stack window without title bar, you could use this script:

```
on grabWindow
  if the platform is "MacOS" and (the decorations of the defaultStack contains "title" or the decorations of the defaultStack is "default") then
    put 22 into myMenuCorrection
  else
    put 0 into myMenuCorrection
  end if
  put "10,10,310,310" into myRect
  add myMenuCorrection to item 2 of myRect
  lock messages
  put (trunc(the width of this window/2) - the mouseH) into difH
  put (trunc(the height of this window/2) - the mouseV) into difV
  repeat until the mouse is up
    put the loc of this window into loc1
    put the screenMouseLoc into loc2
    add difH to item 1 of loc2
     add (difV + myMenuCorrection) to item 2 of loc2
    if loc1 is not loc2 then set the loc of this window to loc2
  end repeat
  unlock messages
end grabWindow

on mouseDown
  grabWindow
end mouseDown
```

I copies this script from a project of mine. Actually, you may not need the entire script and you might think it is a little verbose, but sometimes it could be useful to do a correction for the menubar.